# Find next substring after a string/token in a big string

Tags: java, string, substring, java.util.scanner

In Java,
I have string like this :

```
String str = "PropertyNameAndStringValue[VERSION,5.3.1.20]],family=kwaas,filesize=939888640,imageType=OVA_SW(10000),name=ISR4451X-WAAS-5.3.1.20.ova,updatedTime=February 13, 2014 3:41:22 PM IST,version=5.3.1.20,instanceId=13325317,authEntityId=13325317,authEntityClass=-72900124,_orderedListOEIndex=<Integer>,_creationOrderIndex=<Integer>,instanceVersion=0]"
```

I need to extract Name : which is next to "name=". I need to find the next immediate word after "next=" which is here in this case "ISR4451X-WAAS-5.3.1.20.ova".

How can I do that ?

I tried this

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    String nameOVA = sc.next("name=");
```

I'm getting java.util.InputMismatchException. Pls help

Comment: You mean `split` ? look at `String#split()`  method.

Answer (score 2):

Simply try this out. I know this is not most elegant way to do it, but it should give desired output.

```
String str="PropertyNameAndStringValue[VERSION,5.3.1.20]],family=kwaas,filesize=939888640,imageType=OVA_SW(10000),name=ISR4451X-WAAS-5.3.1.20.ova,updatedTime=February 13, 2014 3:41:22 PM IST,version=5.3.1.20,instanceId=13325317,authEntityId=13325317,authEntityClass=-72900124,_orderedListOEIndex=,_creationOrderIndex=,instanceVersion=0]";

System.out.println(str.split("name=")[1].split(",")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int indexOfName = str.indexOf("name=");
indexOfName += 5;
int indexOfComma = str.indexOf(",", indexOfName);

string name = str.substring(indexOfName, indexOfComma);
```

This gets you the starting index of the name, and where it ends.  Then you use the substring method to extract the string between those two indices.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try these codes::

```
static String str = "PropertyNameAndStringValue[VERSION,5.3.1.20]],family=kwaas,filesize=939888640,imageType=OVA_SW(10000),name=ISR4451X-WAAS-5.3.1.20.ova,updatedTime=February 13, 2014 3:41:22 PM IST,version=5.3.1.20,instanceId=13325317,authEntityId=13325317,authEntityClass=-72900124,_orderedListOEIndex=<Integer>,_creationOrderIndex=<Integer>,instanceVersion=0]";

public static void main(String[] args) {
 String[] property = str.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < property.length; i++) {

        String[] name = property[i].split("=");

        for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {

            if (name[j].equals("name")) {

                System.out.println("Name : " + name[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output will be::  `Name : ISR4451X-WAAS-5.3.1.20.ova`

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that COMMA is appearing several times in the string. Below is the working solution:

```
package com.tokenizing;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class ParseString {
    static String str = "PropertyNameAndStringValue[VERSION,5.3.1.20]],family=kwaas,filesize=939888640,imageType=OVA_SW(10000),name=ISR4451X-WAAS-5.3.1.20.ova,updatedTime=February 13, 2014 3:41:22 PM IST,version=5.3.1.20,instanceId=13325317,authEntityId=13325317,authEntityClass=-72900124,_orderedListOEIndex=<Integer>,_creationOrderIndex=<Integer>,instanceVersion=0]";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] strArray = str.split(",");
        for(String s : strArray) {
            if(null != s && !s.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "=");
                String key = "";
                String value = "";
                while(st.hasMoreElements()) {
                    key = (String) st.nextElement();
                    try {
                        value = (String) st.nextElement();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("String is not formatted correctly for key [" + key + "], ignore and proceed go next element.");
                    }

                    if(key.equals("name")) {
                        System.out.println("Value of 'name' attribute is: " + value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
String is not formatted correctly for key [PropertyNameAndStringValue[VERSION], ignore and proceed go next element.
String is not formatted correctly for key [5.3.1.20]]], ignore and proceed go next element.
Value of 'name' attribute is: ISR4451X-WAAS-5.3.1.20.ova
String is not formatted correctly for key [ 2014 3:41:22 PM IST], ignore and proceed go next element.
```